# Force page reload with html anchors (#) - HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

Say I'm on a page called `/example#myanchor1` where `myanchor` is an anchor in the page.
I'd like to link to `/example#myanchor2`, but force the page to reload while doing so.

The reason is that I run js to detect the anchor from the url at the page load.
The problem (normally expected behavior) here though, is that the browser just sends me to that specific anchor on the page without reloading the page.

How would I go about doing so? JS is OK.

Comment: You could also just re-run the script that reads the url after clicking the link without having to reload the page.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would suggest monitoring the anchor in the URL to avoid a reload, that's pretty much the point of using anchors for control-flow. But still here goes. I'd say the easiest way to force a reload using a simple anchor-link would be to use

```
<a href="?dummy=$random#myanchor2"></a>
```

where in place of `$random` insert a random number (assuming "dummy" is not interpreted server side). I'm sure there's a way to reload the page after setting the anchor, but it's probably more difficult then simply reacting to the anchor being set and do the stuff you need at that point.

Then again, if you reload the page this way, you can just put `myanchor2` as a query parameter instead, and render your stuff server side.

**Edit**
Note that the link above will reload in all circumstances, if you only need to reload if you're not already on the page, you need to have the dummy variable be more predictable, like so

```
<a href="?dummy=myanchor2#myanchor2"></a>
```

I would still recommend just monitoring the hash though.

Comment: The string doesn't have to be random, but just has to be guaranteed to be different. Therefore, you can just use Date.now(), with resolution down to milliseconds, as in window.location='/example/?x='+Date.now()+'#myanchor2'.

Comment: I used the above to force the refresh of a server generated list on a page, but adding in a anchor to get back near the list. window.location.reload(true) would only go back to the top of the page, requiring the reader to scroll down to the list again.

Comment: A little late, but if you go this way google may find this a duplicate content. Be sure that you use canonical tags to prevent this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Comment: @Marco isn't the point that the content should be different (being the reason for the reload), in which case the extra indexing might actually make sense.

Answer (score 35):

Simple like that

```
<a href="#hardcore" onclick="location.reload()">#hardcore</a>
```

[an example](http://qry.me/blej)

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do that is to set the url, and use `window.location.reload()` to force the reload.

```
<a href="/example#myanchor2" 
    onclick="setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 1)">
</a>
```

Basically, the `setTimeout` delays the reload. As there is no `return false` in the onclick, the `href` is performed. The url is then changed by the `href` and only after that is the page reloaded.

No need for jQuery, and it is trivial.

Comment: What is the benefit of delaying the reload? `onclick="location.reload()"` works fine.

Comment: thanks. In my case it worked only with `setTimeout` .

Comment: I think the `setTimeout` is to give the browser a chance to change the url (to include the anchor hash). Without it, the page reloads but without the new location/url.

Comment: Mine too only worked with setTimeout -- better answer than the one above.

Answer (score 7):

My favorite solution, inspired by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612657/4249576) is:

```
<a href="#myanchor2" onclick="location.hash='myanchor2'; location.reload();">myanchor2</a>
```

`href` link will not be followed so you can use your own preference, for example: `""` or `"#"`.

Even though I like the accepted answer I find this more elegant as it doesn't introduce a foreign parameter. And both @Qwerty's and @Stilltorik's answers were causing the hash to disappear after reload for me.

Comment: You probably don't want to reload if the current page has no hash and in some cases you want the anchor link applied before the reload. What I did was: onclick="if(location.hash) setTimeout(function(){location.reload(), 100}"

Answer (score 4):

What's the point of using client-side JS if you're going to keep reloading the page all the time anyways? It might be a better idea to monitor the hash for changes even when the page is not reloading.

[This page](http://blixt.org/js) has a hash monitor library and a jQuery plugin to go with it.

If you really want to reload the page, why not use a query string (?foo) instead of a hash?

Comment: true. found a way around it, but the question mark works (needs to be random to work more than once in a row)

Comment: That link is dead

Answer (score 3):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned yet is to bind event listeners (using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for example) to the links that you care about (might be all of them, might not be) and get the listener to call whatever function you use.

**Edit after comment**

For example, you might have this code in your HTML:

```
<a href="example#myanchor1" class="myHash">example1</a>
<a href="example#myanchor2" class="myHash">example2</a>
<a href="example#myanchor3" class="myHash">example3</a>
```

Then, you could add the following code to bind and respond to the links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.myHash').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the browser from handling the link normally, this stops the page from jumping around. Remove this line if you do want it to jump to the anchor as normal.
        var linkHref = $(this).attr('href'); // Grab the URL from the link
        if (linkHref.indexOf("#") != -1) { // Check that there's a # character
            var hash = linkHref.substr(linkHref.indexOf("#") + 1); // Assign the hash to a variable (it will contain "myanchor1" etc
            myFunctionThatDoesStuffWithTheHash(hash); // Call whatever javascript you use when the page loads and pass the hash to it
            alert(hash); // Just for fun.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note that I'm using the jQuery [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select the links I want to 'monitor', but you can use whatever [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you want.

Depending on how your existing code works, you may need to either modify how/what you pass to it (perhaps you will need to build a full URL including the new hash and pass that across - eg. http://www.example.com/example#myanchor1), or modify the existing code to accept what you pass to it from you new code.

Comment: what event would I bind to figure out when the hash changes? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's something like what I did (where "anc" isn't used for anything else):

```
<a href="/example?anc=myanchor2"></a>
```

And onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = document.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash.length == 0) {
        var anc = getURLParameter("anc");
        if (anc != null) {
            hash = document.location.hash = anc;
        }
    }
}
```

The getURLParameter function is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript/11582513#11582513)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this its help for me**

`<a onclick="location.href='link.html'">click me</a>`

In your anchor tag instead of

`<a href="link.html">click me </a>`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reload the page using the **same anchor** and expect the browser to return to that anchor, it won't. It will return to the user's **previous scroll position**.

Setting a random anchor, overwriting it and then reloading seems to fix it. Not entirely sure why.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
window.location.hash = Math.random();
window.location.hash = hash;
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another answer, monitoring the hash is also an option. I ended up solving it like this so it required minimal code changes. If I had asked the original question, I believe I would have loved to see this option fully explained.

The added benefit is that it allows for additional code for either of the situations (hash changed or page loaded). It also allows you to call the hash change code manually with a custom hash. I used jQuery because it makes the hash change detection a piece of cake.

Here goes!

Move all the code that fires when a hash is detected into a separate independent function:

```
function openHash(hash) {

  // hashy code goes here

  return false; // optional: prevents triggering href for onclick calls
}
```

Then detect your hash for both scenarios like so:

```
// page load
$(function () {
  if(typeof location.hash != typeof undefined) {
    // here you can add additional code to trigger only on page load
    openHash(location.hash);
  }
});

// hash change
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  // here you can add additional code to trigger only on hash change
  openHash(location.hash);
});
```

And you can also call the code manually now like

```
<a href="#" onclick="openHash('super-custom-hash')">Magic</a>
```

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding simple question mark:

`<a href="?#anchor2">Going to Anchor2 with Refresh</a>`