# Javascript reload the page with hash value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refresh the page with this statement in external javascript file after some processes.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

It perfectly reload the page but I want to scroll to the specific location after reload.
So, I put this on the page.

```
<a name="uploadImgSection"></a>
```

And change the javascript to

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "#mypara";
```

This code doesn't reload/refresh the page either

```
window.location.hash = "#uploadImgSection";
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

When I do that, it doesn't reload the page at all. Is there any way I can reload the page with scroll bar position?

Comment: Use a PHP file to redirect to the new page?

Comment: No just html page. The purpose is refresh the page after running some javascript functions and scroll it back to that paragraph's position.

Comment: how are you calling `window.location.href`? if you are doing that on page load and you are hitting f5 and you are using firefox (or other browser that scrolls where you were before the f5 on refresh) this _might_ be the problem

Answer (score 180, accepted):

```
window.location.href += "#mypara";
location.reload();
```

First add the hash, then reload the page. The hash will remain there, and the page gets reloaded.

Tested, works.

---

**ps:** If a hash already exist in the URL, you may want to directly change it via `location.hash` instead of `.href`.

Comment: One other thing. It did refresh the page but it includes post data after the reload. How can I clean those? Those post data are preventing me to delete the data row.

Comment: Please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location  It does include those POST data which is preventing me to do other postback events.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about POST. You can ask a new question about it though, if you want to.

Comment: Well, I had to use query string at last. "window.location.href = url + "&action=reload";". Check action query string in javascripot on page load event, and do this "window.location.hash = "#uploadImgSection";". It's not the way it should work but I had to this way to make this work for now.

Comment: Yup Genius in our midst :) Best solution

Comment: Maybe this worked in 2012, but today this forces a full reload rather than using cache.  That's only supposed to happen if you call reload(true), but Firefox at least is just doing a full reload, which is definitely not what you want to happen.

Comment: @GlennMaynard That’s probably because you had you devtools opened. According to the HTML spec it should not do a full reload, but it does depend on the browser vendor.

Comment: Doesn't work when the content upon the anchor grows on reload - it navigates to the position where the anchor used to be before the reload, not to where it actually is.

Comment: This doesn't work if the hash value is not modified (i.e. you reload expecting the browser to return to the same anchor). It will return to the previous _scroll position_.

Answer (score 43):

I wanted to update this question because I found that using `window.location.href += "#mypara"` will keep appending the parameter to the url even if it exists. I have found the better way is to use

```
window.location.hash = "#mypara"
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 31):

This is really an old post, I would still try and answer with right combination of answers.

1. `location.reload()` and `location.reload(true)` works like F5 on browser. This will post all the form data back to the server if previously load had done it.
2. `location.href` will not refresh the page until there is a URL change recognized by the browser. change in hash (#paramname) doesn't qualify for URL change and hence just doing 
   `location.href+="#paramname"` will not work.

So, `location.href+="?anything#paramname"` should reload the page as a new request as `?anything` is change in the URL.

Comment: Nice answer. Here is a cooked version:
window.location='<?php echo $_POST['back'] ?>&rand='+((new Date()).getTime()%1000000000)+'#myhash';

Comment: Another one: location.href+='&rand='+Math.rand()+'#myhash';

Comment: IMO this answers the question the best compared to the other posts. It requires no change to the underlying code that may have been written as part of a library for example.

Comment: Johan, Math.rand() should be changed to Math.random()

Comment: The closest answer (maybe the other answers were correct in 2012, but they're all wrong in 2018), but it has the problem of adding entries to the user's address bar history, which isn't good if you were just trying to refresh the same history state...

Comment: This is a great answer because the key to understanding this behavior of URLs is in it: "... change in hash (#paramname) doesn't qualify for URL change ". Does anybody have a good reference which explains why this is so?

Comment: awesome answer,  so far the only thing which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
var loc = location.hash;
location.hash = " ";
location.hash = loc;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  What is this doing? Why does it work?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
           var urlString=window.location.href;
           var url=urlString.split("#")[0];
           window.location.href = url + "#mypara";
```

Comment: This doesn't reload the page at all either.

Comment: "Try this" code only answers aren't very useful.  What's it doing? Why does it work?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
var tabValue = document.URL;
window.location = tabValue.substring(0, tabValue.lastIndexOf("#"));
window.location.hash = "#tabs-3"; //Whatever is your hash value
location.reload();
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
$('body').on('click', '.className', function () {
    var data = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(data);
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This seems to basically be a longer way of doing what other answers already do, plus I don't think it includes the #myPara part so won't work like the original poster wants it to, although please edit the answer to clarify that if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This work for me

```
window.location.href = baseUrl + "#/m/team";
 location.reload();
```