# How do I reload a page with an additional hash using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh the page with an additional hash in the url. The problem is that the hash is added but the page is not reloaded which I want in this case. I have tried the following:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.mydomain.com/page1#test";
```

The hash is added in the url but the page is not reloaded. How do I achieve this functionality?

Comment: please explain what you wanna do after reloading the page ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value Please try to do little research effort before posting new question.

Comment: You can change hash without reloading. By just using `window.location.hash = <string>` http://jsfiddle.net/UM429/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
location.reload(true);
```

after you've changed the url -

```
window.location.href = "http://www.mydomain.com/page1#test";
location.reload(true);
```

Check out this example from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.232.3A_Force_reloading_the_current_page_from_the_server).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirement you can as well use [`onhashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange)

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    if (location.hash === "#test") {
        test();
    }
}
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/hashchange)