# refresh a page with hash location

Tags: jquery

So how can I refresh to clicked linked location that is using hashes for each links?

---

Ok, have a look at this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#header-menu .moduletable:last-child .menu li:nth-child(1) a, #header-menu .moduletable:last-child .menu li:nth-child(2) a, #header-menu .moduletable:last-child .menu li:nth-child(3) a').on('click',function(){

    var opts=['Offer','Inquiry','Suggestion'];
    var hash = window.location.href; 
    var hashoption = hash.split("#");
      if(hashoption[1] == "Offer"){
          $('#message_type').val("Offer");
      }
      if(hashoption[1] == "Inquiry"){
          $('#message_type').val("Inquiry");
      }
      if(hashoption[1] == "Suggestion"){
          $('#message_type').val("Suggestion");
      }
var thishash = $(this).attr('id');
//thishash = thishash.split('#');
window.location.href = window.location.href + thishash;
//location.reload();
});
});
```

I've updated my site and you can see link url in the address bar the has is different and the form option is different when you click to another links but if you re-click then it is working so this means it's working on double click.

[you can see a live site here](http://nepotech.com/kldugar/)

contact link you can see on top right side of window.
and three links are under the search box that contains three images of links.

How can I make this in single click?

Comment: Request you to improve your english .. very poor clarity, your question has :(

Comment: @Arun I also request you to re-read the question. And tell what words or sentence didn't you understand?

Comment: Get the hash from the URL used to call the page (`location.hash`), and select the right option accordingly on page load.

Comment: may be you are looking for something like this.. :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value

Comment: Advice: That spash screen should only show once, not every time you click "home".

Comment: @DannyThunder Thanks for your advice. I was also doing the same but not success with session so currently I've left that part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add some JS to the "contact page" to change it instead of reloading the whole page creating unnecessary traffic?

```
$("#Offer").click(function(){
    $("#message_type").val('Offer');
});
```

And so on...