# The onclick function not work in safari

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me on this how can i use hash function to go to another tab or id without location.reload();.

it should be needed to go to the download tab or id without needing to refresh the page.

here is my code

```
<script>
function Download() {
   window.location.hash = "#Download";
   location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to use JavaScript for this? What about just using #href attributes to go to another `<a>` link on the page?

Something like this:

```
<a id='first' href='#second'>Go to Second Link.</a>
<a id='second' href='#first'>Return to First Link.</a>
```

See this fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/3axqpr1x/1/

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one;

```
<script>
function Download() {
   window.location.hash = "#Download";
   location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Please refer this page [Javascript reload the page with hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value)

Comment: I am not finding any difference between the snippet in question and snippet you provided except there is missing semicolon in this line  window.location.hash = "#Download"

Comment: its the same with my code my meaning of this is i need to go to #Download without refreshing the page.

Comment: You can post a comment like "nothing wrong with your code", no need in a pointless and useless answer just repeating the same code. It's just noise.