# When click on div multiple times will not refresh: Only refreshes once

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

When I click on my button I it can refresh div once fine but if I go to click it again will not refresh div.

I have to reload page by clicking on F5

Question: How ever many times I decied to click on my button How can make it to be able to refresh the #rep div?

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.success == true) {
        //window.location.reload();
        $('#rep').load(window.location.href + ' #rep');
    } 
}
```

Full Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vote-up-icon').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('thread/voteup/');?><?php echo $thread_id;?>",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                voteup: $(this).parent().find('#vote_up').val()
            },
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true) {
                    //window.location.reload();
                    $('#rep').load(window.location.href + ' #rep');
                } 
            }  
        });
    });
});     
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center">
<div id="rep">

<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x" id="vote-up-icon" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
<input type="hidden" name="vote_up" id="vote_up" value="1" />
</div>

<div class="form-group" class="votes">
<?php echo $thread_votes;?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x" id="vote-down-icon" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
<input type="hidden" name="vote_down" id="vote_down" value="0" />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you add `#rep` to your URL. If you are already on a page and then load an anchor (`#...`) it won't refresh the page, but it will follow the "in page" link.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value

Comment: This will happen if `vote-up-icon` is a child of `rep`

Comment: ***⇑⇑⇑*** Ya, you'd need to delegate click event

Comment: @wolfgang1983 happy to help. Currently lying in bed on my phone browsing SO...

Comment: @Isaac But this has nothing to do with OP's issue... ;)

Comment: Im on my phone, i saw hash urls, something about not loading correctly, was thinking "maybe its not reloading cos its already loaded the anchor"

Comment: @Isaac, I would suggest you to get off phone and have a sound sleep :), just a banter

Comment: Its too late for sleep :(

Comment: I'm quite sure this would result in dupe IDs: `$('#rep').load(window.location.href + ' #rep')` because it means set `#rep` content as `#rep` element. So e.g: `<div id="rep"><div id="rep"></div></div>`. I'm never sure if `load()` and fragment URL load targeted element content or element itself BUT the doc suggests it is loading element itself: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: I have added the HTML section

Comment: So try: `$('#rep').on('click', '#vote-up-icon', function(e) {...});`  and be sure you aren't generate invalid HTML markup with duplicate IDs, see my previous comment. In your case it would be: `$('#rep').parent().load(window.location.href + ' #rep');`

Comment: Use `delegate` instead of `on`

Comment: @MAZux No, `on()` is preferred, `delegate` is deprecated

Comment: @A.Wolff I think you way worked the best

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Feel free to post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Thanks to [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) and every one else

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rep').on('click', '#vote-up-icon', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('thread/voteup/');?><?php echo $thread_id;?>",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                voteup: $(this).parent().find('#vote_up').val()
            },
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true) {
                    $('#rep').load(window.location.href + ' #rep');
                } 
            }  
        });
    });
});     
</script>
```