# hide div based on anchor value

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a page with 2 divs that can be hidden.  Now when I load the page the URL looks as follows

`www.example.com/wedding.php#pyromusicals`

or it could be

`www.example.com/wedding.php#just-fireworks`

now im trying to hide a different div depending on the anchor value and if there is no anchor then hide them both.  Here is my code so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get # parameter
    var param = document.URL.split('#')[1];


    if (param == 'pyromusicals') {
        $(".hidden-div2").hide();
    } else if (param == 'purely-fireworks') {
        $(".hidden-div1").hide();
    } else if (param == '') {
        $(".hidden-div1").hide();
        $(".hidden-div2").hide();
    }

});
```

The problem is that on page load neither works but if you manually hit refresh then the jquery starts working. The links on the page are just html links

```
<li><span><a href="/wedding-fireworks.php#pyromusicals" title="View information about pyromusical displays for weddings">Pyromusicals</a></span></li>
<li><a href='/wedding-fireworks.php#purely-fireworks' title="View information about wedding fireworks"><span>Purely Fireworks</span></a></li>
```

In fact ive just noticed that in IE it doesn't work at all.  Only in Chrome does it work after a page refresh

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what might be keeping jQuery from working until you refresh (assuming that is what's happening), but try using window.location.hash to get the anchor instead of splitting the document URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved it from another post on stack.  So when the second anchor is clicked the page does not refresh it just moves.  To force a refresh ive put another var in the url

so

www.example.com#pyro

became

www.example.com?string=1#pyro

this made the page refresh

answer taken from

[Force page reload with html anchors (#) - HTML & JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573979/force-page-reload-with-html-anchors-html-js)