# Same page link_to syntax with params, anchor, and class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a `link_to` that goes to the current page (show) that includes new merged params, an anchor (so that it reloads at a certain point), and a html class for the link. However, I cannot figure out the syntax.

This is what I currently have:

```
 <%= link_to "Link Name", params_helper_function, anchor: "anchor-name", class: "class-name" %>
```

I have also tried:

```
<%= link_to "Link Name", object_path(@object, anchor: "anchor-name"), params_helper function, class: "class-name" %>
```

However this did not work either.

Note params_helper function is just a helper function that carries out all the require params logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force page reload with html anchors (#) - HTML & JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573979/force-page-reload-with-html-anchors-html-js)

Comment: Not really, I am looking for help with the rails syntax.